# Is there a way to bind a RMQ alternate exchange to the default exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, messagebroker, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm developing a project in which I'd like to use RabbitMQ as message broker. So far, I use the default exchange to fill the queues and moreover I use the default MQTT exchange, namely *amq.topic*, to handle MQTT messages. Since I would like to avoid lost messages and data, I read on the docs about alternate exchanges.

Then, I'm asking if is possible and there is a way, using Python pika package, to create an alternate exchange and bind it to the default exchange and the *amq.topic* exchange.